# Dynamic %%First Name%% personalization issues with French accents

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

Using MOVABLE-INK to display customer name with custom fonts in email as an image. In outlook 2016 PC French name with accent is not showing at all looks like a broken image path, even after using the URLEncode function.
Did anyone experience this issue?

```
%%[var @FirstName set @FirstName = [First Name]]%%

%%[
  VAR @encodedEmailFName
  SET @encodedEmailFName = URLEncode(@FirstName,1)
  ]%%

  <a href="http://www.example.com?mi_name=%%=v(@encodedEmailFName)">
   <img src="someimage.png? mi_name=%%= v(@encodedEmailFName) =%%"/>
  </a>
```

using Movable-Ink

Comment: I see some curly-quotes in your image src tag.  Is that on purpose?

Comment: What character encoding are you using in the Email Properties?

Comment: Am using UTF-8.  The curly quotes is when copy paste. It’s good in my email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix for the PC Outlook issue. What I did is URLEncode the [First Name] first and then concatenate it to the URL. Then in the SRC I used RedirectTo or TreatAsContent both works.

%%[
SET @FisrtName = [First Name];
SET @endCodefirstName = URLEncode(@FisrtName,1,1)
SET @concatIMg = Concat('http://www.someimage.png?','mi_name=%%=v(@endCodefirstName)=%%')
]%%